# Trying to find the right hook for WooCommerce Order Submission

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin I developed that connects a WooCommerce order to HubSpot. The issue i'm running into though is that while it works, the hook im using right now is sending order info to HubSpot *before* its technically complete. So this means that stuff like Failed orders get sent in as Pending, and coupon codes are ommitted.

So i'm wondering what the right hook to use is.

My goal: Everytime a WooCommerce order is created & completed *and* a WooCommerce order is updated, send the data to HubSpot.

What I have so far:

```
add_action('save_post_shop_order', 'printout', 10, 3);

function printout($post_ID, $post, $update)
{
    if (!is_admin()){
        return;
    }

    if($update){
        $msg = $post_ID;
        $order = get_woocommerce_order($msg);
        mainplugin($msg, $order);
    }

}


add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'neworder_delegator', 10, 2);


function neworder_delegator($order_id, $order){
    mainplugin($order_id, $order);
}
```

So I guess i'm just looking for the right hook to get me what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer:

Each WooCommerce Order transition has one or more dynamic hooks that trigger when the status transition happens.

They start with 'woocommerce_order_status_' and the remaining part of the action is either the new status that the order has transitioned to, or the to and from statuses involved in the format '<status_transition_from>*to*<status_transition_to>'

**Examples**

You can hook your function to

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'your_order_completed_function');
```

To trigger your function only when the order transitioned to completed, and **not** when refunded, cancelled, on-hold, etc. as those would run on other actions such as

```
woocommerce_order_status_refunded
woocommerce_order_status_cancelled
woocommerce_order_status_on-hold
woocommerce_order_status_failed
woocommerce_order_status_processing
```

Edited to add link to official WooCommerce docs:

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

Comment: Your comment made me smile, thank you @sylargaf happy to help :)